# How can I create a popup in Windows with the results of a command called in a .bat file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm calling an exe in a .bat file that returns quickly and I'd like to popup a message box with the results of the text so I can read it (after the program has ended).  My .bat looks like this:

`curl.exe -someparameters`

What do I need to do to make that show a message box after the curl call?

EDIT: If there's a better way to do this with PowerShell I'm up for that too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
curl.exe -someparameters
pause
```

Answer (score 2):

If notepad would be OK for your popup window, then you could use the following.  In this case, you would just click on the red X in the upper right instead of an OK button.

```
@echo off
curl.exe -someparameters > %TEMP%\output.txt 2>&1
notepad output.txt
del %TEMP%\output.txt
```

The `2>&1` will redirect both STDOUT (standard-out) and STDERR (standard-error) to output.txt.

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me.  Is it missing a line to launch notepad?

Comment: Oops, fixed.  Add the notepad line!

Answer (score 1):

Substituting your results for "foo" below:

```
@echo MsgBox "foo" > %TEMP%\msgbox.vbs
@cscript //NOLOGO %TEMP%\msgbox.vbs
```